# Insert Personal Detail to database Table

Tags: database, jsp, netbeans-8

i having problem updating the personal detail into my database table, cos i'm just a new to netbeans. it's show me this error.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
type Exception report
messageInternal Server Error
descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'CURDATE' is not recognized as a function or procedure.
root cause
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'CURDATE' is not recognized as a function or procedure.
root cause
org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: 'CURDATE' is not recognized as a function or procedure.
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.
```

Register.jsp

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>

<%
String fname = request.getParameter("first");    
String lname = request.getParameter("last");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
String dob = request.getParameter("dob");
String user = request.getParameter("userID");
String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Parts");
Statement st = con.createStatement();


 int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into ADMIN(firstname, lastname, email,gender, userid, password, dob, regdate) values ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "','" + gender + "','"+ user +"','" + pass + "','" + dob +"', CURDATE())");

  if (i > 0) {

    response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");

} else {
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}

%>
```

mainRegister.jsp

```
    %@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>Personal Detail</title>

    </head>



    <body>

    <h1 align="left">Personal Detail</h1>

    <form name="myform" action="display.jsp" method="POST">


        <table border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name : </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="first" required="required" size="50" value="">

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name : </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="last" required="required" size="50" value="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email Address : </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" required="required" size="50" value=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date Of Birth : </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="dob" value="DD/MM/YYYY" required="required" size="15" value=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name : </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="userID" required="required" size="15" value=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password : </td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="pass" required="required" size="15" value=""/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Confirm Password : </td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="pass" required="required" size="15" value=""/></td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Already registered!! <a href="login.jsp">Login Here</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="clear" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Error message is clear, `CURDATE()` is not a function or a procedure in your database.

If you want to insert current date use `CURRENT_DATE` in your query.

```
int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into ADMIN(firstname, lastname, email,gender, userid, password, dob, regdate) values ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "','" + gender + "','"+ user +"','" + pass + "','" + dob +"', CURRENT_DATE)");
```

I would suggest using [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of [Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)

Comment: Hi@Karthilkeyan Vaithilingam, i'm still having error on this. Very big thank you for your help.

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error type Exception report messageInternal . Server Error descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exceptionjavax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLDataException:

Comment: The syntax of the string representation of a date/time value is incorrect.
root cause-java.sql.SQLDataException: The syntax of the string representation of a date/time value is incorrect.

Comment: root cause org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: The syntax of the string representation of a date/time value is incorrect.
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.